# Perl module Mac::PropertyList for plist XML files

Tags: perl, plist

I am using `Mac::PropertyList` module for reading plist compatible `XML` file. The function `plist_as_perl()` returns the `plist/XML` file contents in an "`unblessed perl data structure"`. Here is where I am stuck as I do not know how to access data contained in it.

Here is the program

```
use Mac::PropertyList;

print "\nbefore parsing the plist ...";
my $data  = Mac::PropertyList::parse_plist_file("abc.xml");

my $pvar = Mac::PropertyList::plist_as_perl($data);
```

Now how to use pvar?

Thanks

Comment: create $pvar as `$pvar = $data->as_perl;` (see below)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what is inside the structure, you can use [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDumper):

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $pvar;
```

Comment: $VAR1 = '$VAR = ARRAY(0x828f5a0)'

Comment: It does not seem to be a data structure. It is a string.

Comment: OK, may be, it has read a whole XML file. how to print this string?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Data::Dumper or YAML or JSON or Data::Dump or Data::Dump::Streamer or any other module that... dumps data and dumping the variable. Or use the debugger.

**update**: I found it works fine if you create pvar like this: `my $pvar = $data->as_perl;` then you can dump it.. Don't ask me why though ;--(

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the Data::Dumper to print pvar and output was $VAR1 = '$VAR = ARRAY(0x828f5a0)', but how I can get real useful data contained in pvar?

Comment: I have no idea, I have never asked a question here! Don't sweat it, it's no big deal.

Comment: Huh, plist_as_perl was documented incorrectly. It's supposed to return a Perl code string, like Data::Dumper.

Comment: @briandfoy I thought you might butt in. Are you sure it's not a bug in plist_as_perl? I thnik as_data is more useful there actually, to get the data structure without any objects

Comment: Well, it's a bug in that it doesn't do what I wanted it to do and it's confusing.